# I want to mod how IE generates cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

There are two different websites that people use, let's call them A and B. Now, as far as login page goes, A and B are nearly identical in design, but the user account logins for A and B are stored in separate datatables and information is different. When someone logs into A, IE will store their info in a cookie and will call it when going on B, even though they are not the same. Nowhere in the login web forms can I find code for generating the cookie, so I am assuming that everything is done within IE. I found the file 'index.dat' that supposedly stores all of IE's cookies in each user's AppData folder, but I do not know how to access it, let alone change the way IE stores the cookies.

My goal is for IE to have distinct cookies for A and B.

Comment: If you're doing a typical forms auth ASP.NET application, then the auth cookies are generated server-side and sent to the client in the login response.

Comment: IE just stores cookies... cookies themselves are generated by the server and sent in HTTP header to client!

Comment: Where can I find the code that generates these cookies?

Comment: @Yahia, Is that correct? Can't JavaScript generate cookies client-side?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Javascript can generate cookies client-side.  Yahia is probably referring to the asp.net membership items

Comment: If you need A and B to be in the same domain, you could try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5403817/119549

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko yes it is possible to generate cookies client-side (for example with javascript)... usually they are created server-side... IE itself (or any other browser) does NOT generate cookies as implied by the OP...

Answer (score 3):

Place the sites on different domains. If the sites share a domain, they will see each other's cookies. You can't change this. It's how cookies work.

Answer (score 2):

So I suppose you want to change default asp.net forms authentication cookie names to something else.

Something like this in web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="myCustomCookieForApp1" ... />
  </authentication>
```

You can read up here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: The website is authenticated by <authentication mode="Windows">, not forms.

Answer (score 0):

The only way IE will send the cookie for A to B is if they are on the same domain and you haven't configured the login mechanism to limit the cookie to your subdomain.

See [sub-domain cookies, sent in a parent domain request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865345/sub-domain-cookies-sent-in-a-parent-domain-request)